# calendar in input type html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The scenario is, want to make `input type` box in table `td` and it having a calendar icon in its right side. The input type have a `placeholder "21-Jun-17"` and `on click of input type a calendar should open.`
I am looking for `calendar api` that fits my need and it should be cross-browser? Second, a calendar icon should be at its right of input?

Note: The above scenario should work in every browser.

```
<html>
   <body>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <input type="text">    /`*logic to have a calendar icon at right and have a placeholder "21-Jun-17" and onclick open a small calendar where date is seletable*/`
       </td>
     </tr>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO,did you tried something so far? If yes paste your effort. It's Ok that it's not working, we will check and try to rectify it for you

Comment: well i have tried to put fontawesome icons but its not visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is the html5 date input, which does not require any customization, but has limited browser support.

Example:

```
<input id="date" type="date">
```

Read more:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)
- [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)
- [Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#date-state-(type%3Ddate))

If you would like something that does work in every browser you would have to either come up with your own solution or use something like the [jQuery UI data picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), which brings a lot of bloat.

Answer (score 1):

This would help,

```html
<html>
<body>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="date" id="date">    
</input>
</td>
</tr>
</body>
<script>
document.getElementById("date").valueAsDate = new Date("2017-06-21");
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Gowtham, but <input type="date" >  not works in all browsers.